# C program console exits immediately after execution?

Tags: c

I am using Code::Blocks for programming and yeah i am a beginner but everytime i write a program it pauses in IDE but does not pause while executing directly.

What is the possible reason ? Can anyone explain me ?

My code goes as follows :

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    float length,breadth,Area;
    printf("Enter the value of length and breadth \n\n");
    scanf("%f %f",&length,&breadth);
    printf("You entered length=%f and breadth=%f \n\n",length,breadth);
    Area= length * breadth;
    printf("The area of the rectangle is %f\n\n",Area);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's a console application. It's meant to be run from the console. And `main` must return `int`.

Comment: Please use the appropriate formatting next time. Instead of typing `<br>` after each line of code (which still doesn't format it as code), you can just highlight the code and click the "Code" button.

Comment: That's how console applications are supposed to work! If I typed `ls` and it listed the files in the current directory and then waited for input, I'd be pretty annoyed.

Comment: It's the IDE that pauses once your program have finished. It has nothing to do with your program.

Comment: and how do i pause within the program ?? @JoachimPileborg ??

Comment: @mistgeek see the answers

Comment: @mistgeek, Open up a terminal and type `./<program name>`. Voila, no closing at the end.

Comment: @chris i didnt get you ??

Comment: @mistgeek, Rather than double click the program or whatever you're doing, run it like you would run `dir` or `mkdir` or any other console program. By making it a console application, you're saying that this is how it's meant to be run.

Comment: @chris but i want it working in any way i run it ??

Comment: @mistgeek , don't forget to accept and upvote answers and comments which helped you

Answer (score 6):

You have to tell your program to wait for input at the end otherwise it will execute, do exactly what you wrote in your code and exit. The "good" way would be to execute it from a terminal (cmd if you are on windows)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float length,breadth,Area;
    printf("Enter the value of length and breadth \n\n");
    scanf("%f %f",&length,&breadth);
    getchar(); // catch the \n from stdin
    printf("You entered length=%f and breadth=%f \n\n",length,breadth);
    Area= length * breadth;
    printf("The area of the rectangle is %f\n\n",Area);
    getchar(); // wait for a key
    return 0;
}
```

**Why do you need a getchar() after your scanf()?**

When you enter your numbers you finish it with a press of enter. Let's see what you are reading: a float whitespaces and another float. The `\n` is not consumed by `scanf()`, but left in the input buffer (`stdin`). The next time you use a function that reads from `stdin`, the first sign this function sees is a `\n` (Enter). To remove this `\n` from the input buffer you have to call `getchar()` after `scanf()` which reads 1 character from the input buffer. I'm sure you will encounter this behaviour more often in future.

Comment: still not solved :( the console exits immidiately ??

Comment: this is probably caused by your scanf(). scanf() most likely leaves the \n (Enter) in the input buffer which is then catched by the last getchar. I made an edit to my post. try it this way.

Comment: yeah you helped me Thank You but can you please explain why you used getchar() there in the middle and the last ?? and will this not cause any problem in execution on versions of windows ??

Comment: @mistgeek thats mentioned in the comments of his code

Comment: yeah you did but exactly why is it necessary and why does it make a difference ??

Comment: The first one is to get the enter key(/n) that is pressed after entering the values(clear the stdin) and the other is for waiting for a key to be pressed

Comment: @mistgeek, I added an explanation for you to the answer. hope that makes it clear

Answer (score 3):

As a really, REALLY bad practise, you can just use a getch call to stop the excecution (or any function that generates a small pause, getch is not a standard function).

Comment: yeah thanks ill keep that in mind :) but please help me resolve this issue ??

Comment: @mistgeek ,you can use a getch(); at the end of your program before the return

Comment: Alternatively, you can run the program from the standard command line. It should run, and then return to the prompt.

Comment: uh thanks for your help but someone helped me but thank you man :)

Answer (score 3):

A program is not supposed to pause after execution and this is a feature added by the IDE. If you want execution to pause and wait for some input you should instruct it to do so. For instance if you are on windows you can add a line:

```
system("pause");
```

Right before `return 0;`. This is not advisable, but may help you for debugging in some cases. Also the standard requires that your main function is int, not void.  So you better get used to writing `int main` instead of `void main`.

Comment: thanks you helped me :) but i have one question ?? does system("PAUSE") works on all Windows OS if i execute ??

Comment: @mistgeek ,yes it does

Comment: @mistgeek yes it works. However this will not work on a linux system

Comment: yeah thanks man p.s i dont have any knowledge about linux systems :)

Comment: It does not reliably work on Windows. The user could easily have replaced the `pause` utility or have another `pause` program that is found first.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use getch(); at the end of program (Before return statement)
Getch holds down the output screen.

Comment: -1 This has already been posted as an answer by NightwalkerUY.