# Can't get right answer

Tags: c

PROBLEM: Create a loop that, for a positive integer n, finds the biggest integer k for which n ≥ 2<sup>k</sup>.  (We are essentially finding the integer log base-2 of n.)  Do not use pow, log2, or any functions from math.h to implement this!

Last printf statement doesn't work.

My solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int k=1, n, j=2;
    printf("Enter positive number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    while(n>=j*k){
        k++;
    }
   
    printf("k: %d", k);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? The "k: %d" is printed just fine in my pc.

Comment: Through your description I guess you want to find the biggest integer k for which `n ≥ 2^k` rather than `n ≥ 2k`. Could you clarify this?

Comment: adding to @Ynjxsjmh, you should print ```k-1``` not ```k```

Comment: If a printf seemingly "doesn't work", it is often caused by stdout being line-buffered. Try adding `\n` to the end of the format string (i.e. `printf("k: %d\n", k);`).

Comment: If you are using one of those applications that quits immediately after the program executes, you might want to pause the program for a while (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24780415/c-program-console-exits-immediately-after-execution)

Comment: For large values of `n`, `j*k` is subject to overflow.  Post values used.

Comment: Never write “doesn't work” as a problem description. Always say what the program did, what you wanted the program to do instead, and, if not completely clear, what the difference is. Also provide all information people need to reproduce the problem, which includes sample input data. Edit the question to provide a [mre] that includes this input data, observed output data/behavior, and desired output data/behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It works,
beside the result is incorrect, you may want to print the k-1 value.
Reason you are not seeing it may depend on missing "\n" at the end of printf() which do not refresh the output buffer

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Jack's (correct) answer, you might consider a different solution to the problem: use bit shifting operations. Given the problem asks for log base 2, one can count the number of "shift right" operations that are required to make `n` zero.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int k = -1;
    unsigned long int n;
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s n\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    n = strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    while (n) {
        k++;
        // Shift the bits in n to the right by one place. Equivalent to n /= 2.
        n >>= 1;
    }
    printf("%d\n", k);
    return 0;
}
```