# Fix scripts Disappear when use getline() Function in C++

Tags: c++, getline

Hi I have a code that's look's like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
      string name, classes;
      cout << "Enter your name:" << endl;
      getline(cin, name);
      cout << "Enter your class:" << endl;
      getline(cin, classes);

      cout << "your name is " << name << "and your class is in " << classes << endl;  

      cout << "\n\n";
      system("pause");
      return 0;
}
```

and while I compile it compiled successfully without any warning or error message but, when I try to run the scripts it's suddenly disappear. how can I solve this problem? please someone help me

I recently use g++ version 9.2.0

Comment: the compiled executable

Comment: I dont have any antivirus installed in my computer

Comment: No the executable file is not deleted. it's just when I run it, it's doesn't display anything just the window script is disappear suddenly

Comment: What you have is a console app. See [C program console exits immediately after execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24780415/c-program-console-exits-immediately-after-execution).

Comment: "disappear" that i mean is when I run the exe file it should gets a string from a keyboard and display it in the screen, meanwhile the script it's close suddenly

Comment: yes that's what i mean :)

Comment: but i've already add system("pause")  code that should pause the programs. but the programs is exit suddenly

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63276568/edit) the details in the last few comments into the question. But 1) I cannot duplicate it, the program does wait for input, and 2) `system("pause")` is non-standard and unnecessarily heavy.

Comment: You can try running it from a terminal instead of double clicking it

Comment: but if i didnt use getline() instead i use cin.getline function it's works fine

Comment: yes i've already runs it from terminal but it doesnt display anything