# Can't open CodeBlock exe file in my File Explorer

Tags: c, windows, exe, codeblocks, prompt

i can't open the EXE file generated by Code::Block in my File Explorer. When I open the .exe file of my Code::Block program a screen pops up and shutdown 0.25 seconds later... Same when i try to start it in cmd or powershell prompt, but work perfectly in CodeBlock.

Code::Block 20.03 installed under C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks
Path added C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin
Path where is saved my prog. C:\storage\CodeBlockFile\MyProg

(Currently on Windows 10)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C program console exits immediately after execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24780415/c-program-console-exits-immediately-after-execution)

Comment: @Axalo: OP states that the problem also occurs when executed from "cmd or powershell prompt". If OP's statement is correct, then it is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Code::Blocks does not generate executables.  It is an IDE it launches a toolchain to generate executables.  Your use of Code::Blocks is irrelevant.  Most likely your code simply runs to completion without emitting any output or waiting to accept any input.  To that end you need to post your code, because nothing in the question as it stands points to any specific problem.  Are there _any_ error messages when run form the command line?

Comment: What exactly happens when you run the program from a `cmd.exe` command prompt? Does a new window open, instead of the output of your program appearing in the `cmd.exe` window?

Comment: There is not enough information to answer your question. Please describe what exactly happens, what "screen" pops up, and how does it look when it does work in CodeBlocks, what is your program normally supposed to do? Can you show a screenshot of the "normal" behavior? Maybe post the program itself?

Answer (score 0):

When you open an .EXE file in cmd ..The cmd run the code and instantly shuts the window..To solve this issue try using getch(); at the end of ever code so that after running the code the program asks the user to press a key....and also include <conio.h> header like....#include<conio.h> at the beginning..
After pressing a key the window will shut itself.  For eg..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main(){
int a,b;
a=2,b=5;
printf("The sum of a and b is %d",a+b);
getch();
return 0;
}
```